# iOS development: guaranteed top layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Is it possible to programmatically (not via xib) add a button or other control on an arbitrary iOS app which is *always* on top? I want to make a bit more advanced screenshot app where the developer has to put (preferably) one line of code in his app which will show a button in the left top (for instance) and when the user clicks that it screenshots and opens a layer which, again, is guaranteed on top to enter some information and share via Twitter.

Can that be done and how?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you are looking to develop a library or framework that anyone can include in their app, and this will give you a constantly visible button regardless of what the app is showing underneath?

Answer (score 1):

You could either just make sure to call:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:topView];
```

Or possibly add it to you app delegate window:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[delegate window] topView];
```

Note: this will be on top of *all views in every view controller* until you remove it.